# How to use lxml to get a message from a website?

Tags: django, lxml

At exam.com is not about the weather:

```
Tokyo: 25°C
```

I want to use **Django 1.1** and **lxml** to get information at the website. I want to get information that is of "25" only.

HTML exam.com structure as follows:

```
<p id="resultWeather">
    <b>Weather</b>
    Tokyo:
    <b>25</b>°C
</p>
```

I'm a student. I'm doing a small project with my friends. Please explain to me easily understand. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is more suitable for html parsing than lxml.

something like this can be helpful:

```
def get_weather():
    import urllib
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    data = urllib.urlopen('http://exam.com/').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    return soup.find('p', {'id': 'resultWeather'}).findAll('b')[-1].string
```

get page contents with urllib, parse it with BeautifulSoup, find P with id=resultWeather, find last B in our P and get it's content

Comment: Thanks. I already know how to do it. However, still an issue. I want to get the 2nd "b", rather than the last. Parameters to do this?

Comment: Well? I don't know how exactly it works, but from the last line it is obvious, that you should supply a different list index.

Comment: Try using `.findAll('b')[1]` instead of `.findAll('b')[-1]`.

Comment: You can check out pyquery aslo. It has jquery-like syntax and is built ontop of lxml, so it's much faster than BeautifulSoup.